# Cant start mongoDB on Amazon Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I started mongoDB with the following command:

```
 mongod  --auth --port 27017 --dbpath  /var/lib/mongo
```

I was able to successfully connect to mongo with the mongo shell.
Then stopped the process by doing `ctrl+c`.
now when I try to start it with the above commande again, I get this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.894+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.896+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.896+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":21545,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ip-172-31-35-217.ec2.internal"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"amazon2","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)","version":"Kernel 4.14.138-114.102.amzn2.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27017},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:50:56.897+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

So I tried multiple ways to stop the process. But the process did not get killed. I also tried to run the same command with the `--shutdown` option, then it said "killing process whatever" but it left hanging and never ended the command. I also tried to run the same command with a different port but it also gave me errors:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.697+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":21444,"port":27018,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ip-172-31-35-217.ec2.internal"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"amazon2","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)","version":"Kernel 4.14.138-114.102.amzn2.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.699+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27018},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.700+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /var/lib/mongo directory"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.700+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.700+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.700+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:42:00.700+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only stopped the Mongo shell (or maybe `mongod` forks into the background by default and you don't have direct ctrl+c control over it).

You could use `pkill -f mongod` to kill all processes with `mongod` in the name. I wouldn't necessarily do that on production MongoDBs, though, but this seems like a development environment.

Comment: this is the errors I got: `{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:52:38.274+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:52:38.274+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-08T20:52:38.274+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n**
`

Comment: You may need to clean up (=remove) that `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` manually then.

Comment: I did it and now it gived me again the error code 9001 "Address already in use"

Comment: "again"? You never mentioned that error code before... Either way, you'll need to figure out if there are any `mongod` instances running before trying to start a new one; `ps aux` shows you all processes, and `ss -ltpn` shows all listening sockets with their processes.

Comment: OK thank you very much. I was able to stop the process. I also restarted it with `mongod  --auth --port 27017 --dbpath  /var/lib/mongo`. the Problem is, I want it to run in the background. How can I run it in the background? just starting it with `systemctl start mongod` fails and also doesn't pass in the `--auth` option.

Comment: You can edit the systemd unit file to add the `--auth` option...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221210/discussion-between-meilech-wieder-and-akx).